# htaccess rule delimiters and params for smooth urls

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use htaccess rewrite rules to create smooth urls.  So that the user can call for example `http://members.clubseat.at/demo/login/?test=123` and for my code it is like the user called `http://members.clubseat.at/demo/index.php?page=login&test=123`.

here is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*/)?([^/]*)/?$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

I want that the user can leave the additional params after the page and also the last slash, so that `.../demo/login/` and `.../demo/login` also work. But if there is no last slash (**/**) `login` is not in the first param but in the second.

compare: 
http://members.clubseat.at/demo/login/ **vs.**
http://members.clubseat.at/demo/login

try demo here: http://members.clubseat.at/demo/login/?test=123

but according to regex-tester it should work: https://regex101.com/r/nK9rM2/2

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use QSA flag to append query strings to the target url.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)?/?([^/]*)/?$ ./index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The third perm is automatically appended by the QSA flag.

Comment: many thanks @Starkeen this fixes my problem with the additional params. but i still have the problem with `login` and `login/`. with a **/**  login is in get-param p1, but without  a **/**  login is in get-param p2.  updated my .htaccess in the example: http://members.clubseat.at/demo/login/

Comment: @Mmo 
I edited my answer to fix the old regex pattern `^([^/]*/)?([^/]*)/?$` The problem is in your pattern, ([^/]*/) means **any char but not the / followed by a /** it  matches login/ but fails to match /login, so the request without a trailing slash was being captured by the second capture group ([^/]*)/? because / is optional in it. See the regex in my edited answer.